# Send email via Exacttarget using Salesforce force.com platform

Tags: apex, marketing-cloud, email

Is it possible to send email using exacttarget APIs via a apex class from a force.com application ?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by creating a Triggered Send on any object that has a lookup to a Contact ID or Lead ID using `et4ae5.triggerUtility.automate()`. Refer to the Apex code and procedural steps [documented here](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/integrated_products__crm_and_web_analytic_solutions/marketing_cloud_connector_v5/sending_emails/triggered_sends/).